# Input huge amounts of integers into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, input, dynamic-arrays

I have a frustrating problem with inputting huge amount of numbers into an array using std::cin (although I don't care whether it's cin or something else). I have to store, say, up to a million integers into an integer array, and have come to a solution which, for some reason, only works for the 842-843 first inputs.

My code at the moment:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    size_t array_size;
    size_t sum;

    std::cin >> array_size; //let's say array_size = 10000

    int* _nums = new int[array_size];

    for(int i = 0; i < (int)array_size; i++)
    {
        //everything goes fine if I put something like 500 as the array_size
        std::cin >> _nums[i];
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is no error whatsoever. The program simply stops doing anything, as if it was waiting for input (rest of the 823762 inputs).

Comment: "I have a frustrating problem" is absolutely meaningless if you don't tell us **what the problem is** you're having. "My code doesn't work" and a chunk of code is not an answerable question here. Please edit your question and provide information about the problem; we can't read your mind.

Comment: Is the problem not obvious? Instead of reading all of the 100000 inputs, it only reads up to 842.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja In fact I still don't get it exactly. When you enter the 843th number it just gets stuck ?

Comment: Can you give the input file (just a part, the begin and around the 842 line) ?

Comment: `size_t` is unsigned. You may be losing percision due to the cast. Have you tried making `i` be of `size_t`?

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja, there is no place in this code that can indicate it got stuck, so how do you know?

Comment: Well, I just ran your code on my machine, and it happily read 10 million random numbers written by another program I have. I didn't check that all the input was working. But it suggests that there's something other than your code that is wrong - for example, the input may be bad?

Comment: $log0 You could say that. I have generated a list of 10000 random numbers with php which I then copy into the program and press enter (yes the php-generated text is properly formatted to be pasted in to the console). The program then reads the first 842 numbers as it should, but stops after that, waiting for input. It should read it all the way to the last number but it doesn't do that.

Comment: this might be related to console buffer. Did you try to read from a file by redirection?

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja Ok. Be careful then. Your problem may be due to your terminal only handling past of a limited size...

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use something like: `std::vector<int> nums((std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin)), std::istream_iterator<int>());` and be done with it?

Comment: Any chance you're slamming your console input buffer size up against a wall ? try it with a console loaded with just the digit `1` and a space and see if you get significantly more entries in your list.

Comment: $BAK, well it goes something like this:
5900 6647 7240 79 930 6281 6161 5826 6671 5771 7248 7272 4149 6133 2038 1573 4094 6463 3876 5559 2346 1838 3455 1654 3272 3636 3616 25 3605 2554 2024 485 6775 3367 7133 801 7274 7223 5997 5194 4620 7129 7722 817 6978 ... ... 3326 3253 7449 2297 etc...

Comment: @JerryCoffin my first thought as well.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja Do you have a unix terminal ( linux or cygwin ) ? then simply copy the input in a file and do: `cat file | ./your_program`

Comment: Even in Windows command prompt , `type file | program` or `program < file` will work just fine - that has been working in MS OS's since MS-DOS 2.2, I believe - possibly before that, but I didn't use DOS before around that time.

Comment: Problem seems to be solved. Console buffer, as WhozCraig said it, got slammed up against a wall. Thanks a heck to all'o'ya

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, add error checking, i.e. replace your current code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    size_t array_size;
    size_t sum;

    std::cin >> array_size; //let's say array_size = 10000

    int* _nums = new int[array_size];

    for(int i = 0; i < (int)array_size; i++)
    {
        //everything goes fine if I put something like 500 as the array_size
        std::cin >> _nums[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

with e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>        // std::vector
#include <stdexcept>     // std::runtime_error, std::exception
#include <stdlib.h>      // EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <string>        // std::string

bool throwX( std::string const& s ) { throw std::runtime_error( s ); }

void cppMain()
{
    int array_size;

    std::cin >> array_size; //let's say array_size = 10000

    std::vector<int> nums( array_size );

    for( int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i )
    {
        //everything goes fine if I put something like 500 as the array_size
        std::cin >> _nums[i]
            || throwX( "Oops, input failed!" );
    }
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        cppMain();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( std::exception const& x )
    {
        cerr << "!" << x.what() << endl;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Disclaimer: off-the-cuff code, may need fix of typos.